# how to return valide date from database using json

Tags: java, json

I dont know why the date returned as aan unix format,i want to get it like this:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss  this the date field in the class:

```
@Column( nullable = true )
@JsonFormat( pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )
private Date        dateSysteme;
```

the date returned like this :1483616226000 but i want it like this 2017/01/12 21:22:12

Comment: Are you using Jackson?

Comment: yessssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are getting is number of milliseconds past from set standard. you have to format it into required date format.

`Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(yourDate));`

Comment: where i set this??

Comment: whatever `date` you are getting just pass into `format()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would just configure Jackson's ObjectMapper (globally):

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

This also has a `setDateFormat` method.